# How do I set blue light filter by configuring the Intel graphic card settings?

Tags: drivers, graphics, brightness

I am having the Windows and Ubuntu 16.04 dual system on my laptop. In Windows, I used the Intel graphic card settings to tune down brightness, contrast of blue light. And the effect is much better than flux.

On Ubuntu, I am now using the Redshift. While it still can not be compared to the setting by the default graphic card. I did several googling in last several days. But there does not seem to be a article addressing this specific issue. By the way, I am using a Intel HD Graphic 620.

How can I tune down blue light brightness and contrast in driver settings?

Answer (score 0):

I followed the steps by this link:
https://www.techzim.co.zw/2017/06/tuning-intel-graphics-card-ubuntu-16-04/

And after the installation, I went to the folder where the configure file is supposed to be. Type this:

warren@thinkpad:/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d$ ls -a -l

total 44

drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Feb 28 13:35 .

drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4096 Feb 28 13:35 ..

-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   92 Jan 29 13:56 10-amdgpu.conf

-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1099 Jul  6  2017 10-evdev.conf

-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1350 Nov 24 04:51 10-quirks.conf

-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   92 Jan 29 13:58 10-radeon.conf

-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  590 Jul  6  2017 11-evdev-quirks.conf

-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  364 Jul  6  2017 11-evdev-trackpoint.conf

-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  590 Jul  6  2017 51-synaptics-quirks.conf

-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1751 Jul  6  2017 70-synaptics.conf

-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2747 Jul  6  2017 70-wacom.conf

I opened the amdgup.conf, and it is like this:

Section "OutputClass"

```
    Identifier "AMDgpu"

    MatchDriver "amdgpu"

    Driver "amdgpu"
```

EndSection

Wired thing is that, I did not find something like intel.conf.

That is how far I have reached by now. Still don't know how to configure the graphic card.